# Is there a way to extend the cookie size limit per domain in IE11?

Tags: cookies, web, browser, internet-explorer-11

I use the Internet Explorer 11 browser.
I have a requirement to store a large amount of data in cookies.
Reading the Limits per Browser section in http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/, I see that **the max size per domain is 10234 bytes for IE11**.
[image: Limits for IE11]

The data in my cookies is greater than 10234 bytes, and thus some cookies are truncated.

**There is a way to extend the max size per domain for IE11?**
Searching in the web, I found no way for increasing this limit.

Comment: A workaround would be to store the data server-side and fetch it (via Ajax or similar) when needed.

Comment: Do you mean not to have cookies but retrieve the data from the server everytime it is needed?

Comment: You need to store more than what will fit in cookies. If the limit cannot be increased, then you need to store less in cookies. There are several ways to achieve that, perhaps one of these ways works for you: 1. Compress the data so it fits. 2. Don't store (all) the data in  cookies. Instead fetch it from the server when needed. 3. Store (some of) the data in the page (for example in a `hidden` `input` field).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot change the limit. It is also generally bad practice to store much data in cookies.

Have you looked at this alternative: http://www.jstorage.info/